# Looking for a word for "lightly touch"

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word that represents a condition something like "lightly touch" as follows:

1. When I walk on this crowded station, I often feel someone who comes from the opposite direction lightly touches my backhand (dorsal).
2. Last year when I flipped a newspaper, the page corner lightly rubbed my brother's left eyes. His cornea was torn.
3. The opposing car lightly touched my car yesterday night. The scratch was not realized until I washed it this afternoon.

Is there a single word instead of "tip" to represent "lightly touch/rub"?

Comment: 'Glance' or 'brush [against]'.

Comment: *brush* (as @EdwinAshworth suggested).

Comment: If no body wants to answer, I will delete this question shortly. Brush might be the word I am looking for.

Comment: *Brush, touch, scrape, dab, flick, graze, glance, kiss, skim, finger, flip,...* The list is potentially endless, and none are necessarily "better" than any others.

Comment: The reason I responded in a comment rather than an answer was because I consider the question inappropriate on ELU, which is aimed at linguists.

Comment: There is a Linguistics SE for the linguists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ***brush***[e]**d**
2. ***caught***
3. ***grazed*** or ***clipped***